# Confused about Queue and WorkerGroup working?

Tags: apache-dolphinscheduler

Describe the question
foud that source code of sql/dolphinscheduler-postgre.sql has t_ds_worker_group ddl ,
but dolphinscheduler_mysql.sql doesn't have.

confused about t_ds_queue and t_ds_worker_group.

when I define a queue and workergroup,how it working?

Which version of DolphinScheduler:
-[1.3.2]

Additional context
I know that airflow worker(celery executor) can start with queues to consume command from mq, and task can set queue attribute,
so task can run in special worker;
and what about ds working for this

Answer (score 0):

t_ ds_ queue is used to correspond to hadoop yarn queue, The queue in DolphinScheduelr refers to which queue of yarn is used by the tenant, the tenant is binding the queue on the yarn. By the way, you should create queue on yarn first when you want to use

1.3.2 didn't use t_ds_worker_group table any more, because worker set worker group in worker.properties, use worker group table couldn't support k8s, because worker ip always change on k8s